# Variable undefined when getting json from api

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, aws-lambda

I wanna know why is it giving me undefined when I try to get a variable inside my json.

Here's the code I am executing:

```
var options = {
  host: url,
  path: '/api/v1/outside_processes/active_companies?process_token=' + process_token,
  method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.data);
    console.log(data["data"]);
    console.log(data.paging);
  });
}).end();
```

The json coming from the api:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 37
        ...more data
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
          ...more data
    }
],
"paging": 0
}
```

What i am getting in the console:

{"data":[{ all the data is showing here }],"paging":0}

undefined

undefined

undefined

Comment: You need to parse it as JSON.

Comment: ^^ E.g., `data = JSON.parse(data)` as the first line of your callback.

Comment: @SLaks why to need parse json when it is already json

Comment: @Mahi: It's a string.  If you want an object, you need to parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your route is returning the stringified JSON.

Try

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(jsonData)
console.log(jsonData.data)
console.log(jsonData.paging)
```

Comment: I also had to change the data variable to a different name like resp_data, because the variable inside my json was also called data and it was giving me conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

when you console it, if it is a Object it should be displayed as below

```
Object {data: Array[2], paging: 0}
```

as your result shows clearly that it's a string so you need to parse it as told by the above answers